# ModuleNotFoundError when Importing gRPC pb2 File Generated by Protoc in Python

Tags: pytest, protocol-buffers, modulenotfounderror, grpc-python, protoc

I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a generated gRPC module in Python.

In my project, I have a file structure like this:

```py
from test.api.grpc_test_cases.specific_folder.api_pb2
```

- specific_folder contains a proto_files folder with .proto files.
- specific_folder also has test.py files and generated files together.

Here's what my protoc commands look like:

1. First, I generate D.proto because it imports into two other other proto files:

```bash
python3 \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
-I proto_files \
--python_out=. \
--grpclib_python_out=. \
D.proto
```

2. Then, I generate the other protobuf files (A.proto, B.proto, C.proto), which import D.proto:

```py
python3 \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
-I proto_files \
--python_out=. \
--grpclib_python_out=. \
proto_files/A.proto \
proto_files/B.proto \
proto_files/C.proto
```

In my test file, when I try to import a the generated pb2 file, I get the following error:

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_pb2'
```

Here's how I'm trying to import it:

```py
from file.innerfile.innermostfile.api.api_pb2 import ServiceRequest
```

I've tried several things to resolve this issue, including:

- Checking the Python path to ensure the generated modules are in the search path.
- Using both relative and absolute paths in the import statement.
- Generating all protobuf files in a single compiler command.
- Adding "from . import api_pb2" in the grpc.py file.

I expected that one of these approaches would resolve the ModuleNotFoundError issue, allowing me to import ServiceRequest to use in my pytest tests without any errors. I want to use `ServiceRequest` from the pb2 file to create a response object using pytest like this:

```py
response = ServiceRequest()
response.name = "John"
response.id = 123
response.timestamp = "2023-09-18T12:00:00"
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. In my experience, Python, Protobufs and Packages are somewhat of a P-P-P-pain **but** most scenarios are sol(vu)ble. You should **not** need to stagger the `protoc` calls because of dependencies; one should suffice. You may need to add empty `__init__.py` files to some of the generated folders. `protoc` **doesn't** represent `package`'s in Python-generated code which adds complexity.

Comment: Why `--grpclib_python_out`? This should be `--grpc_python_out`.